# How do I convert a str list that has phrases to a int list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that allows me to extract the info obtained from excel to a list, this list contains str values that contain phrases such as: "I like cooking", "My dog´s name is Doug", etc.

So I've tried this code that I found on the Internet, knowing that the int function has a way to transform an actual phrase into numbers.

The code I used is:

```
lista=["I like cooking", "My dog´s name is Doug", "Hi, there"]

test_list = [int(i, 36) for i in lista]
```

Running the code I get the following error:

> builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 36: "I like
>   cooking"

But I´ve tried the code without the spaces or punctuation, and i get an actual value, but I do need to take those characters into consideration.

Comment: `36` is the maximum radix for python's `int` function. What value are those characters (digits) supposed to have, for your purposes? For example, `'0' == 0; '1' == 1; 'a' == 10; ' ' == ????`

Comment: Can you point us to the resource that showed you that the int function can transform strings into integers, i know of no such thing (unless the string happens to be a number, ie. `'1'` or `"564"`

Comment: @3NiGMa, https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int. Also, is `89` a number? It is in base-10, it's not in base-2, base-3, ..., base-7 and base-8.

Comment: @3NiGMa The `int` function can treat alpha-numeric strings as an integer, as long as all the characters are valid for the specified radix.

Comment: thankyou @mypetition, i was not aware of this feature! i guess you learn something new every day...

Comment: @3NiGMa, not really: `int('abc', 34) == 11946`

Comment: as @3NiGMa says i found about that function and tried to used it in phrases but i seem to be unsuccessful, as it seems it doesn´t recognize the punctuation or spaces as i said earlier

Comment: @mypetlion i want to run an ai using those values to give them a classification according to what they say, meaning is they are good, not useful or bad, but i didn´t want to use another ai for that, so that was kinda like my dilemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the `bytearray` approach you could use `int.to_bytes` and `int.from_bytes` to actually get an int back, although the integers will be much longer than you show in your example.

```
def to_int(s):
    return int.from_bytes(bytearray(s, 'utf-8'), 'big', signed=False)

def to_str(s):
    return s.to_bytes((s.bit_length() +7 ) // 8, 'big').decode()

lista = ["I like cooking",
            "My dog´s name is Doug",
            "Hi, there"]

encoded = [to_int(s) for s in lista]

decoded = [to_str(s) for s in encoded]
```

encoded:

```
[1483184754092458833204681315544679,
 28986146900667755422058678317652141643897566145770855,
 1335744041264385192549]
```

decoded:

```
['I like cooking',
 'My dog´s name is Doug',
 'Hi, there']
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i´ve used your code and actually helps a lot, and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, converting phrases to integers with `int()` won't work if the phrase contains whitespace or most non-alphanumeric characters with a few exceptions.

If your phrases all use a common encoding, then you might get something closer to what you want by converting your strings to bytearrays. For example:

```
s = 'My dog´s name is Doug'

b = bytearray(s, 'utf-8')
print(list(b))
# [77, 121, 32, 100, 111, 103, 194, 180, 115, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 105, 115, 32, 68, 111, 117, 103]
```

From there you would have to figure out whether or not you want to preserve the list of integers representing each phrase or combine them in some way depending on what you intend to do with these numerical string representations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to convert your text for an AI, you should do something like this:

```py
import re

def clean_text(text, vocab):
    '''
    normalizes the string
    '''
    chars = {'\'':[u"\u0060", u"\u00B4", u"\u2018", u"\u2019"], 'a':[u"\u00C0", u"\u00C1", u"\u00C2", u"\u00C3", u"\u00C4", u"\u00C5", u"\u00E0", u"\u00E1", u"\u00E2", u"\u00E3", u"\u00E4", u"\u00E5"],
                'e':[u"\u00C8", u"\u00C9", u"\u00CA", u"\u00CB", u"\u00E8", u"\u00E9", u"\u00EA", u"\u00EB"],
                'i':[u"\u00CC", u"\u00CD", u"\u00CE", u"\u00CF", u"\u00EC", u"\u00ED", u"\u00EE", u"\u00EF"],
                'o':[u"\u00D2", u"\u00D3", u"\u00D4", u"\u00D5", u"\u00D6", u"\u00F2", u"\u00F3", u"\u00F4", u"\u00F5", u"\u00F6"],
                'u':[u"\u00DA", u"\u00DB", u"\u00DC", u"\u00DD", u"\u00FA", u"\u00FB", u"\u00FC", u"\u00FD"]}

    for gud in chars:
        for bad in chars[gud]:
            text = text.replace(bad, gud)

    if 'http' in text:
        return ''

    text = text.replace('&', ' and ')
    text = re.sub(r'\.( +\.)+', '..', text)
    #text = re.sub(r'\.\.+', ' ^ ', text)
    text = re.sub(r',+', ',', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\-+', '-', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\?+', ' ? ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\!+', ' ! ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\'+', "'", text)
    text = re.sub(r';+', ':', text)
    text = re.sub(r'/+', ' / ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'<+', ' < ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'>+', ' > ', text)
    text = text.replace('%', '% ')
    text = text.replace(' - ', ' : ')
    text = text.replace(' -', " - ")
    text = text.replace('- ', " - ")
    text = text.replace(" '", " ")
    text = text.replace("' ", " ")

    #for c in ".,:":
    #   text = text.replace(c + ' ', ' ' + c + ' ')

    text = re.sub(r' +', ' ', text.strip(' '))

    for i in text:
        if i not in vocab:
            text = text.replace(i, '')

    return text

def arr_to_vocab(arr, vocabDict):
    '''
    returns a provided array converted with provided vocab dict, all array elements have to be in the vocab, but not all vocab elements have to be in the input array, works with strings too
    '''
    try:
        return [vocabDict[i] for i in arr]

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return []

def str_to_vocab(vocab):
    '''
    generates vocab dicts 
    '''
    to_vocab = {}
    from_vocab = {}

    for index, i in enumerate(vocab):
        to_vocab[index] = i
        from_vocab[i] = index

    return to_vocab, from_vocab

vocab = sorted([chr(i) for i in range(32, 127)]) # a basic vocab for your model
vocab.insert(0, None)

toVocab, fromVocab = str_to_vocab(vocab) #converting vocab into usable form

your_data_str = ["I like cooking", "My dog´s name is Doug", "Hi, there"] #your data, a list of strings

X = []

for i in your_data_str:
    X.append(arr_to_vocab(clean_text(i, vocab), fromVocab)) # normalizing and converting to "ints" each string

# your data is now almost ready for your model, just pad it to the size of your input with zeros and it's done

print (X)
```

If you want to know how convert an "int" string back to a string, tell me.